# rrdtool graph slightly different graph

Tags: rrdtool

First I will say that even after setting up a system where I register the each minute total of http responses (200, 301, 302, etc) and I'm able to know how is going on the performance speaking about users, it happens to me that my boss is getting me mad with something that i thing it is related with rrd internals, but supossedly i must solve that.

What I do with the rrdtool?:

After a minute (60 seconds) summarizing different http responses i insert the value with the time stamp into the rrd database.

This is the rrd file definition:

```
/usr/bin/rrdtool create file.rrd --start $_[7]-60 --step 60 DS:200:GAUGE:120:U:U DS:300:GAUGE:120:U:U DS:400:GAUGE:120:U:U DS:404:GAUGE:120:U:U DS:500:GAUGE:120:U:U DS:502:GAUGE:120:U:U DS:504:GAUGE:120:U:U RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:43200
```

As you can see in the RRA i save 43200 which means two week saving 60 seconds values.

The problem it comes when i draw, this is the command I use to draw the graph of the last 6 hours (Where $start is the start time, $time the end time and $rrd the rrd file)

{`/usr/bin/rrdtool graph last6hours.png  --units=si --alt-y-grid --start $start --end $time -o -S 60 --width 600 --height 200 --imgformat PNG DEF:200=$rrd:200:AVERAGE LINE1:200#006666:"200" DEF:300=$rrd:300:AVERAGE LINE1:300#FF00CC:\"301+302\" DEF:400=$rrd:400:AVERAGE LINE1:400#000000:\"400\" DEF:404=$rrd:404:AVERAGE LINE1:404#6666CC:\"404\" DEF:500=$rrd:500:AVERAGE LINE1:500#00FF66:\"500\" DEF:502=$rrd:502:AVERAGE LINE1:502#FF0000:\"502\" DEF:504=$rrd:504:AVERAGE LINE1:504#FF9900:\"504\"`;}

And this is the one I use to draw the las 12 hours:

{`/usr/bin/rrdtool graph last12hours.png  --units=si --alt-y-grid --start $start --end $time -o -S 60 --width 600 --height 200 --imgformat PNG DEF:200=$rrd:200:AVERAGE LINE1:200#006666:"200" DEF:300=$rrd:300:AVERAGE LINE1:300#FF00CC:\"301+302\" DEF:400=$rrd:400:AVERAGE LINE1:400#000000:\"400\" DEF:404=$rrd:404:AVERAGE LINE1:404#6666CC:\"404\" DEF:500=$rrd:500:AVERAGE LINE1:500#00FF66:\"500\" DEF:502=$rrd:502:AVERAGE LINE1:502#FF0000:\"502\" DEF:504=$rrd:504:AVERAGE LINE1:504#FF9900:\"504\"`;}

And now please look at the draws and see that into the first graph inside the red circle there's a descend of the responses 200 until 0, but into the graph of the last 12 hours the same descend it does not go until 0, so my boss is pressing me saying that the data is not real when it is, but the worst if that i know is real and is about rrdtool internals, but I doon't know how to solve it.

Any subjestion please?

[image: last six hours]

[image: last twelf hours]

Answer (score 2):

this change is due to the fact that rrdtool is consolidating data, adapting it to the resolution of the chart you are drawing. Your initial chart shows high resolution data while the second chart covers a wider time range and thus shows several data points wrapped into one. consider the following:

original: 10,10,10,0,10,10

consolidated 2 to 1: 10,5,10

If you want to preserve extremes, you should setup a MIN and MAX RRA and use that for charting the extremes.

hth
tobi